# C++ boost function issue

Tags: c++, boost

I did something to break the functionality in my program, but I can't figure out what. I define a typedef in a  class headerfile:

```
typedef boost::function<void(instr_ptr, std::vector<ResultBase*>) > GenFunction;
```

And inside that class I have two instances:

```
GenFunction Gen;
GenFunction Kill
```

I set them as follows:

```
void DataFlowSolver::SetGenFunction(GenFunction &func)
{
    Gen = func;
}

void DataFlowSolver::SetKillFunction(GenFunction &func)
{
    Kill = func;
}
```

I have another function in a seperate header file:

```
void GenLiveVar(const instr_ptr instr, std::vector<ResultBase*> &list);
```

I create an instance of the DataFlowSolver class, and attempt to assign into it as follows:

```
blockSolver.SetGenFunction(GenLiveVar);
```

However, the compiler complains:

> CFG.cc:617: error: no matching function for call to 
>   'DataFlowSolver::SetGenFunction(void (&)(instr_ptr,
>   std::vector >&))'
>   DataFlowSolver.h:21: note: candidates are: void
>   DataFlowSolver::SetGenFunction(GenFunction&)

But it lets me do this:

```
GenFunction fun = GenLiveVar;
blockSolver.SetGenFunction(fun);
```

Anyone have an idea what might be wrong? I know this worked before, but I'm not sure how I managed to break it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `boost::function` into `Set*Function` by non-const reference.  That prevents temporaries from being used as arguments, and the conversion from a normal function to a `boost::function` creates a temporary value.  You will need to use a const reference for your parameter type for the code to work correctly.